# Use max yAxis when plotting boolean values

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to figure out a way to plot boolean values in Highcharts using the max yAxis range. I'd like the false value is aligned with the bottom of the chart and the true values is aligned with the top. Highcharts seems to be auto padding the ticks at ~30% and ~70% of the yAxis and I can't seem to find a way to adjust these to 0 and 100%.

Here's a simplified code example I've been experimenting with:

```js
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      title: {
        text: "Valve Position",
      },
      categories: ["on", "off"],
    },
  ],
  series: [
    {
      data: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    },
  ],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `linear` axis type (default) insted of `category`:

```
    yAxis: [{
        ...,
        tickPositions: [0, 1],
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.isFirst ? 'on' : 'off';
            }
        }
    }],
    series: [{
        data: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7v04d3r5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis